# connecting to mysql using php in flex

Tags: apache-flex

Hi I am new to flex, 
I wanted to use flex line chart for displaying data stored in mysql table. Can anyone suggest me on how do I do this with flex as UI and mysql as db, I am not sure how to call .php file in flex to query from mysql. I wanted to show some data of time v/s temperature

I wrote a php file to query data from mysql, but my flex program is not able to connect to mysql, is there any configuration I need to update. I am using XAMPP

Comment: Do you know the HTTPService? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/http/mxml/HTTPService.html You can also configure your backend: rightclick on project -> properties -> Flex Server but I haven't worked with this properties yet.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking theres no extra configuration you need to make this work as hering said in the comment an HTTPService will serve your purposes.  Here's what you need to do:

```
private var myCollection:ArrayCollection;

public function creationComplete(event:Event):void
{
    var myService:HTTPService = new HTTPService();
    myService.url = "myscript.php"
    myService.method = "POST";
    myService.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, resultHandler);
    myService.send();
}

public function resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
{
    if(event.result..entries is ArrayCollection)
        myCollection = event.result..entries;
    else if(event.result..entries is Object)
        myCollection = new ArrayCollection(event.result..entries)
}
```

I'm assuming you're adding a listener to whatever control this service call lives in for creation complete that calls the creation complete function.  I also assume you have (php generate) an xml structure like:

```
<entry>
    <entries>1</entries>
    <entries>2</entries>
</entry>
```

Comment: To note if you see nothing add a listener to the HTTPService for the FaultEvent.FAULT string and you'll get messages if you get something other than an ok message from the server.